# onItemSelectedListener for bottomnavigationbar

Tags: android, android-bottomnav, onitemselectedlistener

I am new to android and Kotlin, developing a bottom navigation bar using onitemselectedListener, since setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener is deprecated and I couldn't find any youtube tutorial that explains how to used onitemselectedlistener for navigationbar. navigation shows up on the emulator, but fragments are not showing up when i click on navigation Icons. here are my codes.

adding image of [activity_main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UFMI.png) and  [emulator error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKH3X.png)

[fragmentWord image, that is connected to the first icon of "A" but doesn't show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5fO2.png)

MainActivity

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.aryanvedh.vocabapp2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val wordFragment = WordFragment()
        val memorisedFragment = MemorisedFragment()
        setCurrentFragment(wordFragment)

        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.words -> setCurrentFragment(wordFragment)
                R.id.memorised -> setCurrentFragment(memorisedFragment)
            }
            true
        }

    }

    private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment) =
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.flFragment, fragment)
            commit()
    }
}```


any help? thanks
````

Answer (score 1):

Use the function like this:

```kotlin
    val navBar = findViewById<NavigationBarView>(R.id.navBar)

    navBar.setOnItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId) {
            R.id.item01 -> {
                setCurrentFragment(Fragment01())
                true
            }
            R.id.item02 -> {
                setCurrentFragment(Fragment02())
                true
            }
            R.id.item03 -> {
                setCurrentFragment(Fragment03())
                true
            }
            else -> {
                false
            }
        }
    }
```

It now should raise the fragments when each navigation bar item is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` Method to capture once the item is selected in Bottom Navigation.

Here is the sample code attached from Documentation.

```kotlin
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when(item.itemId) {
        R.id.item1 -> {
            // Respond to navigation item 1 click
            true
        }
        R.id.item2 -> {
            // Respond to navigation item 2 click
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}
```

Please [refer](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/android#using-bottom-navigation) to the Official Documentation for more information about BottomNavigationView.

Comment: Thanks @Saikiran, I tried what you suggested, but it didn't help as well. still getting the same error. OnNavigationItemSelectedListener deprecated, so I can't use it, my searches suggested using setOnItemSelectedListener which is what I am trying to figure out how it should work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue but the main problem was not with the lambda function `onItemSelectedListner`. The problem is with the view binding, just use the traditional `findViewById` method and you are good to go.